# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando cadastrar meu endereço do cliente e ele da a seguinte mensagem:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
```

Não faço ideia do que possa ser, eu faço a query desta forma:

```
$this->Conexao->prepare($sql)->execute()
```

De acordo com esse erro me parece que ele esta considerando minha variável $sql como null, porém eu pedi pra escrever ela na tela e esta normal. Até porque eu antes de acontecer o cadastro que está dando esse erro o php faz outro antes.

Comment: oi, sua conexão não é válida, verfique usuário, senha ip, banco. Veja no código se não está fazendo alguma atribuição em uma variável local no lugar da propriedade `Conexao`

Comment: Parece q o problema está no$this->Conexao, coloque sua classe inteira para nós vermos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Achei o problema**

O porque de aparecer este erro foi o seguinte.
criei uma classe para se responsabilizar pelo contato e pelo endereço ou seja:

```
class Endereco extends AbsGeral
{
    function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

O erro estava que eu instanciei essa classe assim:

```
$end = new Endereco;
```

Sendo que havia um construct pedindo parametro. Eu simplesmente removi esse construct que nem devia existir e funcionou perfeitamente. Fica ai a dica caso algeum passe pelo mesmo que passei.